# How can I get Pylance auto-imports on Jupyter Notebook VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

Is there any way I can have the Pylance auto-import function on Jupyter Notebooks?

Right now Pylance acts like he doesn't know the package each time I write a function when on a notebook, if I switch to a `.py` file it works perfectly.

```
"train_test_split" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)
```

[image: Image of that ^]

It's such an annoyance having to import manually each time when working on notebooks.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum case to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT set up a Notebook with the VSCode Jupyter Notebook extension, you wont be getting PyLance auto-import in there

Comment: This maybe a bug. I have submitted it to github.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT please link

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered by the Py-Lance team [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2857#issuecomment-1139091098).

The feature wasn't implemented yet but is right now available in the insider VS Code version as of now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dependency Analytics doesn't work with ipynb python cells.

You can disable this extension. Manually change the lower right corner of the cell to python.

[image]

Comment: I think this is not my problem. 
My cells are recognized as Python and colorization of the language happens, the issue you opened on github is a different problem.

Comment: @cZep You can try install the latest version of python including pylance and jupyter notebook.